# NPM Install error - No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm-install

While attempting to install the node, I received the below error

% npm install

Error:

```
/Users/xyz/.asdf/shims/npm: line 7: /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.8.1_1/libexec/bin/asdf: No such file or directory
/Users/xyz/.asdf/shims/npm: line 7: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/asdf/0.8.1_1/libexec/bin/asdf: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. `asdf reshim` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check the file directory to which you are installing it from and change it.
You can use the terminal or command prompt.

Answer (score -2):

A workaround was provided here: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/1147

The issue is When the asdf version number is upgraded, the shim paths are not updated; the solution is to rename the /.asdf/shims directory and run asdf reshim.